# Why does python relative import not work in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I am creating a project to test one web application. The web application is deployed in a docker container, my project is also deployed in a docker container. The project structure for testing looks like this

[image]

The files in the container look like this:[image]

The file containing the tests contains the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from ..pom.loginpage import LoginPage
import Locators
import time

def test_logo(browser_patient):
    log_page = LoginPage(browser_patient)
    log_page.check_logo()
    time.sleep(10)
```

But when I run the test with pytest, I get an error related to an import error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with importing my own classes? Why doesn't the script run in docker container?

Here is the code that works without problems:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import Locators
import time


def test_create_target(browser_patient):
    browser_patient.get("http://192.101.0.1:20080/user-files/view-analysis-file?id=113")
    browser_patient.implicitly_wait(2)
    browser_patient.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value=Locators.FileLocators.LOCATOR_CROS).click()
    browser_patient.refresh()
    assert browser_patient.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=Locators.FileLocators.LOCATOR_CHECKBOX).is_selected() == True
```

Docker-compose code:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  selenium:
    container_name: selenium-test
    build: /home/vitalijj/PycharmProjects/test_connect_to_cont/docker
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
  selenoid:
    container_name: selenoid
    image: "aerokube/selenoid"
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - "/home/vitalijj/PycharmProjects/test_connect_to_cont/config/:/etc/selenoid/" # assumed current dir contains browsers.json
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  selenoid-ui:
    container_name: selenium-ui
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: [ "--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444" ]
  chrome:
    container_name: chrome-vnc-99.0
    image: "selenoid/vnc_chrome:99.0"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - selenoid
```

Please help me understand what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the [python path](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Could be that something locally is doing it for you, like your IDE.

```yaml
environment:
  - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
  - PYTHONPATH=/code
```

May need to double check if its exactly the correct path, but from the looks of it, it is.

Comment: Tried to do it. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: @ВиталийАгарев, not sure why you still get the same error. I know the error you are showing. I usually resolve it through PYTHONPATH. Maybe you need to set the path one directory higher, altough it doesnt look like it. And that would be / which would be also somewhat strange. Maybe nest your folder into a parent dir and try it.